# Iterate over pandas series gives

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Basically I have this pd.series:

```
0         03/25/93 Total time of visit (in minutes):\n
1                       6/18/85 Primary Care Doctor:\n
2    sshe plans to move as of 7/8/71 In-Home Servic...
3                7 on 9/27/75 Audit C Score Current:\n
4    2/6/96 sleep studyPain Treatment Pain Level (N...
```

When I try to iterate over it with a loop:

```
  for i,row in enumerate(df):
    d= row[i].len()
```

Or this:

```
    for row in df:
        d= row.len()
```

I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'len'
```

Also receive this error message when I try other operations like findall etc.

Hope somebody can enlighten me!
Thanks.

Comment: d=len(row[i]) ?

Comment: You can get the length of strings in a Series, with the aptly named [`Sereis.str.len`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html?highlight=series%20str%20len)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Not sure, I'm a beginner, but seems as if there is a difference between dataframe and series when it comes to loops

Comment: @ALollz When I try that in the loop I get the same error

Comment: @user2629628 don't use the loop. First you need a Series, let's call it `s`. (that might be what you call `df` above). Then all you do is `s.str.len()`

Comment: @user2629628 So you're saying I can't use loops on series?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to iterate over rows in a DataFrame in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `.str` to access string functionalities in a `Series` and you don't need to iterate over every rows.

This will do;

```
df['str_len'] = df['str_column'].str.len()
```

By the way in `pandas`, `.findall` is `.str.contains` which returns a boolean indexer.

Use it like this;

```
substring = 'hello'

df[df['str_column'].str.contains(substring)]
```